# Can't get datastax-agent to run on a new node

Tags: apache-2.2, cassandra, opscenter

I'm trying to install the datastax-agent on a new CentOS node (there are 3 other nodes currently up and running correctly).

After installing the datastax-agent via the Opscenter UI it appears to install but still claims only 3 of 4 agents are connected.

The service is running on the new node, upon checking the agent.log I get these errors:

```
ERROR [Initialization] 2014-11-03 15:54:02,035 clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: throw+: {:type :bad-permissions, :message "Unable to read configuration file. Please check that the file exists and the permissions are correct (/home/datastax/dse-4.5.1/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml).\n\nIf running from a tarball install and your configuration is not located with the cassandra install, please set the 'conf_location' option in the Cassandra section of the OpsCenter cluster configuration file and resta                   rt opscenterd."} {:object {:type :bad-permissions, :message "Unable to read configuration file. Please check that the file exists and the permissions are correct (/home/datastax/dse-4.5.1/resources/cass                   andra/conf/cassandra.yaml).\n\nIf running from a tarball install and your configuration is not located with the cassandra install, please set the'conf_location' option in the Cassandra section of the Op                   sCenter cluster configuration file and restart opscenterd."}, :environment {private-props? true, file #<File /home/datastax/dse-4.5.1/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml>}}
ERROR [Initialization] 2014-11-03 15:54:02,036  at opsagent.util.cassandra_util$get_cassandra_conf.in                   voke(cassandra_util.clj:126)
ERROR [Initialization] 2014-11-03 15:54:02,036  at opsagent.opsagent$create_thrift_conf_vars.invoke(o                   psagent.clj:52)
ERROR [Initialization] 2014-11-03 15:54:02,036  at opsagent.opsagent$setup_thrift.invoke(opsagent.clj:140)
ERROR [Initialization] 2014-11-03 15:54:02,036  at opsagent.jmx$determine_ip.invoke(jmx.clj:275)
ERROR [Initialization] 2014-11-03 15:54:02,036  at opsagent.jmx$setup_jmx$fn__2001.invoke(jmx.clj:292)
ERROR [Initialization] 2014-11-03 15:54:02,036  at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
ERROR [Initialization] 2014-11-03 15:54:02,036  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744
```

Comment: Looks like agent’s startup script can’t locate java binary correctly. I think I saw similar problems on centos before, and they were solved by setting JAVA_HOME env variable. Could you run /usr/share/datastax-agent/bin/find-java and post it’s output here?

Comment: Thanks, you were correct I actually fixed that and just edited my question as there is a new bunch of errors (I didn't notice your reply to my original question until I had already edited it)

Comment: And I did run the command you asked after I fixed it and I get:  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java

Comment: I should also add that I did check the configuration file, and the permissions appear to be correct as they match the permissions of the config files on the nodes that are working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Ah it was a silly little thing, for some reason the home directory for the user account needed to run the datastax-agent service had the wrong permissions.  Easy enough to fix once I figured out what was wrong :)